# Is Oracle BC4J Still Supported?

Tags: jboss, oracle-adf

We need to move from OAS 9.0.4 to JBoss and we want to take our BC4J application with us. I'm looking for information on the supportability of BC4J on our new platforma and what licenses would be required.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the licenses requirement, but this tutorial

will explain how to redeploy you bc4j application to JBoss

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/howtos/appservers/deploy_bc4j_to_jboss.html